# Adjust the line height in inno?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Is it possible the Adjust the line height in inno setup
I have 4 lines of text (see pic) and I want to add more space between line to line, is that possible?

[image]

here Is my code:

```
{CB_txt}
CB_txt := TNewStaticText.Create(SPPage);
CB_txt.Parent := SPPage.Surface;
CB_txt.Left := ScaleX(0);
CB_txt.Top := SP_Title.Top +30;
CB_txt.Width := ScaleX(300);
CB_txt.Height := ScaleY(100);
CB_txt.Color := -16777211;
CB_txt.Font.Color := 536870911; 
CB_txt.Font.Name := 'Arial';
CB_txt.Font.size := 9;
CB_txt.Caption := SPCBtext1 + #10 + SPCBtext2 + #10 + SPCBtext3 + #10 + SPCBtext4 ;
CB_txt.TabOrder := 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, without window proc. interception and owner drawing it is not possible since the [`TNewStaticText`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm#TNewStaticText) control is based on the system [`Static Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control and in this case it is the system who renders the control (and who chooses line spacing when word break is enabled). And [`Static Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) itself has no option to setup line spacing, so the only option would be owner drawing.

I would use one [`TNewStaticText`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm#TNewStaticText) control per line.

Comment: P.S. line break is `#13#10` on Windows platform.

Comment: 10x TLama for the info